# Overwrite data in dataframe based on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Suppose I have a csv file with two columns, one with data (a number) and one with the date in a format '193011'.

I have a script/process which generates new data in the form `[data, date]`. I would like code which does the following.

If the `date` does not already appear in the CSV then the new data should be appended to the end of the CSV. This is easy and I know how to do this.

If the `date` DOES appear in the csv then i want to know that (I already know how to do this) and I would like to overwrite the data in the row in the csv which contains that date. I don't know how to do this last part.

So far I am working just with the csv package but I realize this is something that Pandas might be very helpful for. Open to answers with and without pandas.

Also, I know one approach that could work is just re-writing the csv every time data is being added, handling any rows with the same value as the new value of `date` specially but this doesn't seem like a great solution to me.

## Edit 1

Here is the data. Basically  I do an experiment on a certain date and the experiment outputs data into a file called TEK####.csv. The name of the data file and the date are recorded. The data file is then processed to output the numerical values in the `finesse_mean` and `finesse_err` categories. For a variety of reasons the data will be reprocessed and the result of reprocessing should be overwriting the old data or appending to the complete dataset.

```
mirror_1,mirror_2,finesse_mean,finesse_err,cav_length (mm),date,filename,notes,uid
1,4,12784,None,10,191001,TEK0000.csv,,191001TEK0000.csv
1,4,10058,None,10,191001,TEK0001.csv,,191001TEK0001.csv
1,4,21288,None,8,19`1001,TEK0003.csv,,191001TEK0003.csv
1,4,25843,None,7,191001,TEK0002.csv,,191001TEK0002.csv
5,13,43297,579,3.6,191015,TEK0000.csv,,191015TEK0000.csv
14,15,54531,650,4.75,191022,TEK0000.csv,,191022TEK0000.csv
14,15,80444,542,8.45,191022,TEK0001.csv,,191022TEK0001.csv
14,15,43899,61,8.45,191022,TEK0002.csv,,191022TEK0002.csv
14,15,73906,220,8.45,191022,TEK0003.csv,,191022TEK0003.csv
14,15,83946,306,6,191024,TEK0001.csv,,191024TEK0001.csv
14,15,73607,605,7.85,191024,TEK0002.csv,,191024TEK0002.csv
14,15,84402,611,6,191024,TEK0003.csv,,191024TEK0003.csv
13,15,49706,515,6.26,191029,TEK0000.csv,,191029TEK0000.csv
13,15,65547,403,6.26,191029,TEK0001.csv,,191029TEK0001.csv
13,15,63117,306,6.26,191029,TEK0002.csv,,191029TEK0002.csv
14,15,81584,410,6.14,191101,TEK0000.csv,,191101TEK0000.csv
14,16,19782,269,4.85,191101,TEK0001.csv,,191101TEK0001.csv
14,16,18348,130,5.2,191101,TEK0002.csv,,191101TEK0002.csv
14,15,17038,97,12.75,191104,TEK0000.csv,,191104TEK0000.csv
14,15,16620,43,16.8,191104,TEK0001.csv,,191104TEK0001.csv
14,15,13646,49,18.23,191104,TEK0002.csv,,191104TEK0002.csv
3,15,83146,345,4.15,191107,TEK0000.csv,,191107TEK0000.csv
3,15,69347,477,12,191107,TEK0001.csv,,191107TEK0001.csv
3,15,68372,506,13.75,191107,TEK0002.csv,,191107TEK0002.csv
3,15,67950,582,14.4,191107,TEK0003.csv,,191107TEK0003.csv
3,15,66644,564,15,191107,TEK0004.csv,,191107TEK0004.csv
3,9,22883,197,5.5,191108,TEK0000.csv,,191108TEK0000.csv
3,9,21544,274,8.35,191108,TEK0001.csv,,191108TEK0001.csv
1,9,11474,159,7,191108,TEK0002.csv,,191108TEK0002.csv
3,9,21163,413,7.25,191111,TEK0000.csv,,191111TEK0000.csv
1,8,16949,107,4,191115,TEK0000.csv,,191115TEK0000.csv
1,8,9711,77,9,191115,TEK0001.csv,,191115TEK0001.csv
27,28,44092,481,20,191115,TEK0002.csv,,191115TEK0002.csv
27,28,39812,351,20,191115,TEK0003.csv,,191115TEK0003.csv
27,28,69046,722,20,191115,TEK0004.csv,After Cleaning back mirror,191115TEK0004.csv
27,28,82591,291,20,191115,TEK0005.csv,After Cleaning front mirror,191115TEK0005.csv
27,28,97631,205,12,191119,TEK0004.csv,,191119TEK0004.csv
27,28,99560,408,11,191120,TEK0000.csv,,191120TEK0000.csv
27,28,98735,275,11,191120,TEK0001.csv,,191120TEK0001.csv
27,28,98141,184,11,191120,TEK0002.csv,,191120TEK0002.csv
27,28,103222,222,11,191120,TEK0003.csv,,191120TEK0003.csv
27,28,96684,463,11,191120,TEK0004.csv,,191120TEK0004.csv
27,28,102335,313,11,191120,TEK0005.csv,,191120TEK0005.csv
27,28,102698,311,11,191120,TEK0006.csv,,191120TEK0006.csv
1,8,14469,69,8,191121,TEK0000.csv,,191121TEK0000.csv
1,8,16286,128,5,191121,TEK0001.csv,,191121TEK0001.csv
1,8,16143,64,5,191121,TEK0004.csv,,191121TEK0004.csv
1,7,14272,76,4,191121,TEK0006.csv,,191121TEK0006.csv
1,7,12275,80,4,191121,TEK0007.csv,,191121TEK0007.csv
3,9,13582,61,4.8,191121,TEK0008.csv,,191121TEK0008.csv
14,15,30502,174,5,191122,TEK0000.csv,,191122TEK0000.csv
14,15,44951,152,5,191122,TEK0001.csv,,191122TEK0001.csv
14,15,56137,111,6.7,191122,TEK0002.csv,,191122TEK0002.csv
3,9,14177,55,7,191122,TEK0003.csv,,191122TEK0003.csv
27,28,103871,160,7.75,191122,TEK0004.csv,,191122TEK0004.csv
28,2,54449,1069,3,191122,TEK0005.csv,,191122TEK0005.csv
3,28,79357,653,5.00,191126,TEK0000.csv,,191126TEK0000.csv
9,28,10887,55,4.50,191126,TEK0001.csv,,191126TEK0001.csv
9,28,11435,45,4.50,191126,TEK0002.csv,,191126TEK0002.csv
9,28,21184,70,2.40,191126,TEK0003.csv,,191126TEK0003.csv
3,9,14586,181,4.40,191126,TEK0005.csv,,191126TEK0005.csv
3,9,19954,127,9.80,191126,TEK0006.csv,,191126TEK0006.csv
```

I have code that is able to do what I am looking for now which I'll post here shortly.

Suppose I have a new bit of data in the form:

```
3, 28, 21352, 122, 7.5, 191127, TEK0001,,191127TEK0001.csv
```

or old revised data of the form

```
3,9,19954,127,9.80,191126,TEK0006.csv,,191126TEK0006.csv
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share some of the data? I think that rewriting the entire file is the easiest solution, and shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Hmm, I guess I had reservations about that approach because it seems inefficient. The file in my case is very small so there won't be a performance issue. I guess I was worrying for larger files. But I guess even for larger files the step of determining if the date is unique or not requires reading every line of the big file anyways so it's not too much more to write as I go. I will put together some code for the file-rewriting version and post that here to see if anyone can suggest improvements/alternative approaches.

Comment: I can definitely understand why you would want to find a better alternative, I recently had the same question myself. I’m still casually searching for a solution, more so for the sake of learning than anything else. As you said yourself, loading all the data is often necessary, and even if it weren’t you would be wasting far more time reading the file just to avoid a bit of writing.

Comment: If you can share your data, I can take a shot at writing something, too.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Ok, I've posted the data. I'll post my code snippet shortly.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile posted my code as an answer

Comment: Have you considered using Pandas for this? All the rows in the CSV file seem to be missing a column, towards the end of the line, is that normal?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes I have considered using Pandas for this but have been taking this as an opportunity to learn how to directly edit CSV using the csv package. I think Pandas can definitely solve this, I just haven't spent much time yet looking into exactly how. An answer to this question using Pandas would be appreciated. The reason the second to last column is blank on most rows is that it is an optional "notes" column with special notes about any run of the experiment but there typically aren't special notes.

Comment: Alright, I’ll try to write both a `csv` and a Pandas-based solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the below

1) Create a Pandas dataframe(say 'df') with the first record of your file with 
'date' as index and 'data' of your file as one column
2) Then read the file record by record and loop through the below logic

if 'date' in df.index:

```
df = df.drop('date')
df.loc['date'] = data
```

else

df.loc['date'] = data

3) At the end export the data to file from the DataFrame

Let me know if you need guidance on how to create data frame or importing or exporting files. I can update the post

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I've written that seems to do the job. In this code I create a version of the files whose name is suffixed by `_temp` and copy the file contents of the original file onto the new file line by line. If one of the lines duplicates the same dataset of the current scope I input the new data, otherwise the previous data is just copied from the old file. At the end the old file is deleted and the new file is renamed to the old name. The script seems to work fine even if I direct both the csv_reader and csv_writer to the same file but based on what I've read it sounds like that is a possible recipe for disaster and the new file + renaming felt like better practice

```
import csv
import os
from pathlib import Path

def csv_write_overwrite(save_file, data_dict, uid_field='uid'):
    temp_file = Path(str(save_file).strip('.csv') + '_temp.csv')
    new_data_uid = data_dict[uid_field]
    data_saved = False
    with open(save_file, 'r', newline='') as read_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(read_file)
        with open(temp_file, 'w', newline='') as write_file:
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(write_file, fieldnames=data_dict.keys())
            csv_writer.writeheader()
            for line in csv_reader:
                if line['uid'] != new_data_uid:
                    csv_writer.writerow(line)
                elif line['uid'] == new_data_uid:
                    csv_writer.writerow(data_dict)
                    data_saved = True
            if not data_saved:
                csv_writer.writerow(data_dict)
    os.remove(save_file)
    os.rename(temp_file, save_file)
```

### Edit:

I've updated the code by removing the details specific to my particular data structure. Now all that is required is a CSV and data structure which includes some field which can be used a `uid_field`.

Here is another more general version of the code which, instead of checking a particular uid_field to determine if the new data duplicates you can pass in a custom duplicate_checking function.

```
def csv_write_overwrite(save_file, data_dict, 
                        is_duplicate=lambda x, y: x['uid'] == y['uid']):
    temp_file = Path(str(save_file).strip('.csv') + '_temp.csv')
    data_saved = False
    with open(save_file, 'r', newline='') as read_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(read_file)
        with open(temp_file, 'w', newline='') as write_file:
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(write_file, fieldnames=data_dict.keys())
            csv_writer.writeheader()
            for line in csv_reader:
                if not is_duplicate(line, data_dict):
                    csv_writer.writerow(line)
                elif is_duplicate(line, data_dict):
                    csv_writer.writerow(data_dict)
                    data_saved = True
            if not data_saved:
                csv_writer.writerow(data_dict)
    os.remove(save_file)
    os.rename(temp_file, save_file)
```